# Export to .csv - How to deal with non-visible quotation marks?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

i'm trying to make some excel form using VBA Userform, to help our analitycs crete valid .csv files, which is currently use to add data to database. What's necessary - there should be only semicolons and commas as special characters. Unfortunately, when I try export .xlsm file to .csv everything seem to look good, but if I open file on eg. Notepad++ I see extra quotation marks. It looks like this:

Excel:

| ID | GROP | ATTR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234; | GRP_A; | VAL=abc, DT_CON=2022-10-20; etc. |
| 1235; | GRP_B; | VAL=abc, DT_CON=2022-10-20; etc. |

Notepad++:
`1234;GRP_A;"VAL=abc, DT_CON=2022-10-20;" 1235;GRP_A;"VAL=abc, DT_CON=2022-10-20;"`

I tried to save file as some formats (inluding xlCSVUTF8 - but when used this, I got error 1004), use param *Local:=True*. Nothing works like I want. I don't know how to handle this using VBA.

My code:

```
Sub CopyToCSV()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
        'The path and file names:
    MyPath = "C:\Users\BM73LJ\Documents\" ' ThisWorkbook.Path
     'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
    If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
        'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
    Sheets("WYNIKI").Copy
        'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
    MyFileName = MyPath & tb_CorpoKey.Value & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
    ' ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8
    With ActiveWorkbook
        'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
    .SaveAs Filename:= _
        MyFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
    'Closes the file
    .Close False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When you save data to a CSV file, it's a plain-text file where values are *separated* by commas (or maybe semicolons).  What should happen though if a data item *contains* a comma or semicolon?  You don't want those to create field breaks, so typically the whole field gets wrapped in double-quotes to indicate to any application parsing that file that the whole content within the quotes is one data item.  The quotes are *supposed* to be there to preserve the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code like this:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook
        'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
    .SaveAs Filename:= _
        MyFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter 'THIS IS THE CHANGE
    'Closes the file
    .Close False
End With
```

**UPDATE:**

Hey Kooneer, try adding the following changes, it cleans up the cells from certain invisible characters before saving the workbook.

```
Sub CopyToCSV()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
        'The path and file names:
    MyPath = "C:\Users\BM73LJ\Documents\" ' ThisWorkbook.Path
     'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
    If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
        'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
    Sheets("WYNIKI").Copy
    
    With Application
        .calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .enableEvents = False
        .screenUpdating = False
        .Interactive = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
    
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set rng = getDataRange(Sheets("WYNIKI"))
    
    For Each cell In rng
        
        With cell
            
            .value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.value)
            
        End With
        
    Next cell
    
        'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
    MyFileName = MyPath & tb_CorpoKey.value & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
    ' ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8
    With ActiveWorkbook
        'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
        .SaveAs Filename:= _
            MyFileName, _
            FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
        'Closes the file
        .Close False
    End With
    
    With Application
        .calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .enableEvents = True
        .screenUpdating = True
        .Interactive = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Function getLastCell(ws As Worksheet, Optional lookin As Long = xlFormulas) As Range

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    
    With ws
        
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, lookin:=lookin, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, lookin:=lookin, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set getLastCell = .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)
        
    End With

End Function

Private Function getFirstCell(ws As Worksheet, Optional lookin As Long = xlFormulas) As Range

    Dim firstRow As Long, firstCol As Long
    
    With ws
        
        firstRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Rows.count, .Cells.Columns.count), LookAt:=xlPart, lookin:=lookin, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row
        firstCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Rows.count, .Cells.Columns.count), LookAt:=xlPart, lookin:=lookin, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).Column
        Set getFirstCell = .Cells(firstRow, firstCol)
        
    End With

End Function

Private Function getDataRange(ws As Worksheet, Optional lookin As Long = xlFormulas) As Range

    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range
    
    Set firstCell = getFirstCell(ws, lookin)
    Set lastCell = getLastCell(ws, lookin)
    Set getDataRange = ws.Range(firstCell, lastCell)

End Function
```

I do not know if you have also need to used the trim function on every cell to clean spaces. if so you should also add `.Value = Trim(.Value)` inside the loop.

How's your output now??

Comment: A bit of context about the change you're proposing would be helpful.

Comment: It's one of the [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) , this one ensures that the csv file contains the text as it would've appeared as if the excel sheet/workbook was sent to a printer. It's the only workaround that I found to get the csv file saved correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. I tried also xlUnicodeText but without results.

Comment: @edit
Nice, it seems to be working, but now i have blank spaces:
`2311111113;GRP_A;          VAL=12,DT_CON=2022-11-21,TPS_OSN=DISC;`
Is it possible to remove these? Should I wrote all data in one cell?

Comment: @Kooneer check the update on the answer, how is your output now??

Comment: @David Apologies for the long wait for a reply. I simply printed one row in one cell, per line. And that's how I dealed with white spaces. TY in advance for your help.